# How to trigger a task in airflow given the two conditions that only after all parents are done executing and if any of the parent failed?

Tags: airflow

I have a task (say taskA) in airflow which has a bunch of parent tasks. I want the taskA to be triggered only if any of the parent tasks fail along with the condition that all the parent tasks execution is completed.

I have gone through all the trigger rules but none meets my requirement. I don't want the task to be triggered with trigger rule `one_failed` as it will trigger taskA even before all the parent tasks are completed. Can I use some combination or trigger rules or something?

Comment: How about using two DummyOperators. One with ```all_done``` and one with ```one_failed```. Add your taskA after those two dummy operators.

Answer (score 1):

It's "all_failed". We need to route all the parents (tasks[A-Z]) to a task in between (taskBW) which has a trigger rule of none failed. If any of our parents (task[A-Z]) fail, the taskBW will go into upstream_failed state then the child task of taskBW (say taskIfParentFailed) which has a trigger_rule of all_failed will trigger. 
If there are no failures in task[A-Z], then taskBW will pass and taskIfParentFailed will not execute and you can have other children to taskBW with other rules to execute.